# last_request_at value passed as integer in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, warden

I recently upgraded the ruby version of my rails app to 2.6 and I am facing an error with devise.
When authenticating with `warden` the `last_request_at` value is passed as string.

```rb
warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
```

Due to which I am facing an `argument out of range` error.

Here is the value to `last_request_at` which is getting passed to `warden`

```rb
"warden.user.user.session" => {"last_request_at" => "1677703463"}
```

The time should be integer instead of string.

Below is the code in devise gem that is causing the error, found in
`devise/lib/devise/hooks/timeoutable.rb`:

```
if last_request_at.is_a? Integer
  last_request_at = Time.at(last_request_at).utc
elsif last_request_at.is_a? String
  last_request_at = Time.parse(last_request_at)
end
```

`Time.parse` is not able to parse a string but it works when the value is integer.

Is there any way to make sure the `last_request_at` value is passed an integer instead of a string?

Comment: first, you have to downgrade and check if the error is caused due to update ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue and in my case it was because of older cookie_store.rb file, the older cookie_store appends the action_dispach cookie into params and than it gets converted to string along with the request.
Update your cookie_store.rb file from here -
For rails 5.2 - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb